# How can I filter records in an SQLite database against a DateTime value that was not supplied?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, linq, datetime

I have an SQLite database of `TimeRecords`.  When a new record is created, no `EndTime` is provided.
I want to retrieve the first record where the `EndTime` was not supplied and assign it to a new `TimeRecord`

`EndTime` is stored as a `DateTime` variable.

My Current Query

```
public static Models.TimeRecord GetMerchandiserCurrentTimeRecord(Models.Merchandiser merchandiser)
{
    lock (collisionLock)
    {
        return database.Table<Models.TimeRecord>().FirstOrDefault(timeRecord => timeRecord.MerchandiserId == merchandiser.Id && timeRecord.EndTime == null);
    }
}
```

Calling the Query

```
Models.TimeRecord CurrentTimeRecord { get; set; }

// I assign the CurrenTimeRecord in the Constructor
CurrentTimeRecord = Database.TimeRecordDatabase.GetMerchandiserCurrentTimeRecord(SelectedMerchandiser);
```

I have done some [research](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-datetime#:%7E:text=The%20default%20and%20the%20lowest,00%3A00%20(midnight).) and discovered that a `DateTime` does not store `Null` values, but instead defaults to the 1st January 0001 00:00:00.000.

Therefore, I can understand why my above query was not returning any result, so I changed the query to the below, but still I am not retrieving any result.

```
return database.Table<Models.TimeRecord>().FirstOrDefault(timeRecord => timeRecord.MerchandiserId == merchandiser.Id && timeRecord.EndTime == '01/01/0001');
```

Comment: You forgot to give us the class `TimeRecord`. If you have defined property `Endtime` as a nullable `DateTime?`, and defined the corresponding table column as nullable, a null DateTime will be saved as a null. Not as 1st January 0001.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this.  Instead of checking against `null` or a `string` value I checked against a new instance of `DateTime`

Refer to below code

```
DateTime NoSuppliedDate = new DateTime();
return database.Table<Models.TimeRecord>().FirstOrDefault(timeRecord => timeRecord.MerchandiserId == merchandiser.Id && timeRecord.EndTime == NoSuppliedDate);
```

**Edit:** A better way was to use `DateTime.MinValue` as commented by @sqmoore.

Comment: You could also use DateTime.MinValue